# How to change only text inside td of table table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, django-templates

I am trying to update the text inside a cell that contains also an input box.
In line `$(ib).closest('td').prop('textContent',888);` I am assigning the value 888 to the text but this results in assignment of cell's text to "888" but also for some reason deleting the input box.

My code (Django template):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head_scripts %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script/api_recs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/script/site_filter.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

{% endblock %}

{% block title %}
Schedule Match
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
<style type="text/css">
    tfoot {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<table id='pm_table' class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for col_name in table_headers%}
            <th>{{col_name}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            {% for col_name in table_headers%}
            <th>{{col_name}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        {% for data_row in table_data%}
        <tr>
            {% for item in data_row%}
            <td>{{item}}</td>
            {% endfor%}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var SITE_ID_COL = 0;
    var PRIORITY_COL = 3;
    var IS_SCHEDULED_COL = 4;

    // priority input box
    $("#pm_table td:nth-child(" + PRIORITY_COL + ")").each(function() {

        // $(this).children().css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(this).css('text-align', 'center');
        // $(this).css('font-size', 0);

        var $input_box = $('<input type="text" class="priority_changed" />')
        $input_box.prop('value', $(this).text());
        $input_box.prop('size', 1);
        $input_box.css('text-align', 'center');
        $input_box.prependTo(this);
    });
    // remember old value of input box
    $("#pm_table td:nth-child(" + PRIORITY_COL + ")").on('focus', '.priority_changed', function() {
        this.old_val = this.value;

    });
    // priority input box listener
    $('#pm_table').on('change', '.priority_changed', function() {
        var $changed_tr = $(this).closest('td').closest('tr');
        var site_id = $changed_tr.children().eq(SITE_ID_COL).text();
        var old_val = parseInt($(this).closest('td').text());
        var ib = this;

        // confirm change
        if (!confirm('Change priority for site ' + site_id + ' from ' + this.old_val + ' to ' + this.value + " ?")) {
            //revert input box value
            $(this).prop('value', this.old_val);
        } else {
            // make the change in db
            new_val = this.value;
            var url = '/api/manage/schedule_match/set_priority/' + site_id + '/' + new_val + '/';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                success: function(result) {
                    res = JSON.parse(result) // todo read res
                    alert('SUCCESSFULLY changed priority for site ' + site_id + ' from ' + ib.old_val + ' to ' + res.new_val + ".");
                    $(ib).closest('td').prop('textContent',888);



                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('ERROR updating database!');
                    //revert input box state
                    $(ib).prop('value', ib.old_val);
                },
            });
        }
    });      
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried `$(ib).closest('td').text(888);` and many different properties like innerText, innerHtml,`$(ib).closest('td').childNodes[1].prop('text',888)` but without result in right direction. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)?

Comment: `$(ib).closest('td').childNodes[1].prop('text',888);` won't do anything but give you an error.

Comment: sorry, updated the question

Comment: @GillesC has the right of it. In fact, you've already used `text()` to get data out of a `td` for `old_val`. You should also consider changing all of your `prop` calls with their shorter methods, like `val()` instead of `prop('value, )`

Comment: $(ib).closest('td').text(888); leads to same result (deleting the input box of this td)

Comment: You seem to have a load of extraneous code in your question. Please create a [mcve]. It seems as if all you need is a way to change the text of a table cell while leaving the input in the cell alone, but with all the extra noise in your code I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your template to have a `span` inside `td`. Like:

```
<tbody>
    {% for data_row in table_data%}
    <tr>
        {% for item in data_row%}
        <td><span>{{item}}</span></td>
        {% endfor%}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Then you can use `$(ib).closest('td').children('span').text(888)` to change the text without deleting the input box.

Comment: I was just about to advise that haha. Normal standard for `HTML` element manipulation is to separate out responsibility of content.